# Permissions on /tmp and /private/var/tmp

Tags: macos, permissions

I'm having troubles starting XQuartz after *Disk Utilities → Repair Disk Permissions*:

[image]

My permissions are as follows (after `a+w` on `/tmp`). I seem to recall `/tmp` should be a symbolic link, but I'm not certain.

What are the permissions supposed to be on `/tmp` and `/private/var/tmp`?

---

```
$ ls -l /
total 16142
...
drwxr-xr-x@  6 root  wheel      204 Oct  8  2013 private
drwxr-xr-x@ 62 root  wheel     2108 Oct  8  2013 sbin
drwxrwxrwx  13 root  wheel      442 Jul  1 11:00 tmp
```

And:

```
$ ls -l /private/var/
total 24
...
drwxr-xr-x   8 root       wheel       272 Oct  8  2013 spool
drwxrwxrwt   6 root       wheel       204 Jul  1 11:00 tmp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're completely right. /tmp should be a symbolic link to /private/tmp/

`user@host:~ # uname -a ; ll -d@ /tmp
Darwin host.local 13.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel    11B Oct 23  2013 /tmp -> private/tmp
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32B`

I should add that your permissions on /private/tmp/ look correct.

`user@host:~ # ll -d@ /private/tmp
drwxrwxrwt  13 root  wheel   442B Jul  2 09:15 /private/tmp`

Comment: OK, thanks. Now I have to figure out how to make `/tmp` a symbolic link to `private/tmp` while `/tmp` is in use. And I wonder what changed it....

Comment: OS X had somehow screwed up these permissions by itself on my machine, which broke a lot of things. In such situation, use `sudo chmod 1777 /private/tmp` to set the correct permissions again (including the [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit), denoted by `t`).